# Query on Data Categories

Tags: apex, soql, knowledge

I am trying to fetch data category groups and categories, so that i can use it in my VF page.  how do i query(SOQL) so that i can see all available data categories?

[image: Datacategory]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the sObject to find categories for, you can access these using Dynamic Apex (describe calls). This is an example lifted from the [Apex Developer Guide](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_data_categories.htm) that lists all categories available for 
KnowledgeArticleVersion and Question objects.

```
public static List<DescribeDataCategoryGroupResult> describeDataCategoryGroupSample(){
    List<DescribeDataCategoryGroupResult> describeCategoryResult;
    try {
        //Creating the list of sobjects to use for the describe call
        List<String> objType = new List<String>();
        objType.add('KnowledgeArticleVersion');
        objType.add('Question');

        //Describe Call
        describeCategoryResult = Schema.describeDataCategoryGroups(objType);

        //Using the results and retrieving the information
        for(DescribeDataCategoryGroupResult singleResult : describeCategoryResult){
            //Getting the name of the category
            singleResult.getName();
            //Getting the name of label
            singleResult.getLabel();
            //Getting description
            singleResult.getDescription();
            //Getting the sobject
            singleResult.getSobject();
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
    }
    return describeCategoryResult;
}
```