# How to query on data categories in salesforce?

Tags: soql, data-category

`(SELECT Id, ParentId, DataCategoryGroupName, DataCategoryName FROM Info_Hub__DataCategorySelection)`.

In this i did not find complete list of data categories. I want to list up all data categories using query. How can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot query on DataCategories using SOQL, you must forcibly specify the Article Type in order to retrieve the assigned DataCategories of each record for that type.

Example:

```
SELECT DataCategoryName FROM knowledge__DataCategorySelection
```

this is documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_datacat.htm)

You will most likely have to use an apex class to achieve what you want as mentioned in someone elses [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/75325/query-on-data-categories?rq=1)