# Is there a way to include the data categories associated with an object in an outbound message?

Tags: knowledge, workflowoutboundmessage, articles

My org needs to send article data to our Sitecore CMS for publication on our public knowledgebase.

I think setting up a workflow rule with an outbound message for the creation/editing of articles is the way to get this done. I noticed that the available fields to send in the outbound message do not include any of the Data Categories for the article.

Does anyone have any idea how to include data categories in an outbound message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option with outbound messages is to include the current Salesforce Session details. Those will go out with the outbound message.

You can then use the SessionId and ServerURL to establish a connection back into the originating org to pull any further details you require.

The [Knowledge Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_knowledge.htm) schema diagram can be useful.

I'm not an expert on Data Categories, but I suspect you will need to use a SOQL query with the `WITH DATA CATEGORY` keywords. See [KnowledgeArticleVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticleversion.htm)

> Client applications can use KnowledgeArticleVersion with describeDataCategoryGroups() and describeDataCategoryGroupStructures() to return the category groups and the category structure associated with Salesforce Knowledge.
>
> Alternatively, client applications can use the article type API Name followed by __kav to query, retrieve, or search for articles for a specific article type.

See also:

1. Data Categories under [Salesforce Knowledge API Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.knowledge_dev.meta/knowledge_dev/knowledge_customize_api_objects.htm).
2. [Query on Data Categories](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/75325/102)

Comment: Thanks Daniel, since I first posed this question we started looking at using the Salesforce API to dynamically display knowledge articles on Sitecore pages.

Are there any drawbacks to this approach? Will searching and indexing on the external site become less reliable?